# Disable date from datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to disable dates from my datepicker which is the past days and about 30 days after the current date but I think I'm missing something. Here's a snippet of what I got.

Here is the php code.

```
<h3 style="font-family:Lucida Sans; font-size:12px;color:#514C4C;">Reservation Date:</h3>
                <input type ="date" class="inputbox6" value ="<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
                $date = date('M-d-Y');
                echo $date; ?> " id="datepicker" style ="border-top-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px;" name ="res_date"/>
                <div style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:5px; width:220px; color:#F00; font-size:12px;">
                    <?php if (isset($_POST['btnReserve'])) { ?>
                        <?php if (empty($res_date)) { ?>
                                <?php echo "Please choose your reservation date."; ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
```

And Here is the script.

```
<script language = "javascript">
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ minDate:0});
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ maxDate:30});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it inside the document ready handler, and you need to put all the options in one call to `datepicker`:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker( {
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: 30
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jnr3B/)

Comment: thanks for the reply but I've tried it and it still doesn't disable the past days.

Comment: Works for me, see the fiddle.

Comment: weird thing is i have tried it on fiddle and it worked on the past days but the next 30 days it doesn't, and another wierd thing is when i'm using the same codes on my php, <input type = 'text' id = 'datepicker' name = 'res_date'/> when i click inside the textbox it doesn't show the calendar.

Comment: I suspect you're setting the options in multiple places, like you did in the question, so they're overriding each other. Make sure you only initialize the datepicker in one place.

Comment: what do you mean? those are all in one file and that's the only datepicker i have. sorry kind of a newbie.

Comment: Please post a link to your fiddle that doesn't work for next 30 days.

Comment: Can you post a link to your code that doesn't show the calendar?

Comment: You haven't loaded jQuery or jQuery UI in the fiddle, so of course it doesn't work.

Comment: but how do i load jquery or jquery ui in my php so the calendar would work?

Comment: With `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script><script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` in your HTML.

Comment: so i'll just put that below <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> in my file?

Comment: That line loads jQuery. You just need a similar line for jquery-ui.

Comment: i got this
<script src='ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script> and still the jquery-ui doesn't work.

Comment: Are you just typing things without understanding them? You don't need to load jquery.min.js from your own server if you're already loading it from ajax.googleapis.com.

Comment: I think you need to go back to step 1, and learn how this stuff works. I can't spoon feed you every single step.

Comment: yeah sorry about that. my bad mate.

Answer (score 1):

For disabling the current date from the calendar, you can change the input tag as below

```
<input type="date" class="inputbox6" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 days")); ?>" />
```

and to block one month date in the date picker change as follow,

```
<input type="date" class="inputbox6" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 MONTH")); ?>" />
```